# Not able to perform wide HBase table scans

Tags: mapreduce, apache-spark, hbase, hdfs

I'm facing a problem due to a BAD table design in HBase. The problem is millions of records end up under the same row key (1 cf). Till 2.5M I was able to run mapReduces with Spark by scanning a single row, but now some of the rows are reaching 5 or 6 millions and whenever I perform a scan or get, all my regionservers are down within a couple of minutes. I'm working with HDP 2.2 and HBase 0.98.4.2.2

So far I've tried:

```
confPoints.setInt("hbase.rpc.timeout",6000000)
...
scanPoints.setBatch(1000)
```

Before creating a new table with new rowkey design I really need to process this data. I'm new to HBase so maybe some of this suggestions sound stupid but:

- Would increasing java heap size help in any way?
- Is there a possibility of splitting a row into 2 or more rows?
- Can I run a MapReduce over the raw stored data in HDFS without passing through HBase?
- Any other idea?

Thanks!

**EDITED:**

Actually, the second option I think it is not feasible cause hbase doesn't let to update records, just delete + create again.

**EDITED 2:**

Each record in a row is about tens of bytes. The problem when having millions of records per row is when trying to scan this kind of row is that after a couple of minutes region servers start to go down one by one. Maybe trying to get a row of 512MB aprox. is too big for my cluster configuration: 6 nodes of 8GB each.

Searching in the HBase logs the only exception I can find is this on:

```
2015-08-25 15:07:19,722 DEBUG [RS_OPEN_REGION-ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:60020-0] handler.OpenRegionHandler: Opened my-hbase-table,20150807.33,1439222912086.e731d603bb5d1f0d593736eab922069c. on ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.internal,60020,1440528949321
2015-08-25 15:07:19,724 INFO  [RS_OPEN_REGION-ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:60020-1] regionserver.HRegion: Replaying edits from hdfs://ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX2.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/apps/hbase/data/data/default/my-hbase-table/3bc481ff534f0907e6b99d5eff1793f5/recovered.edits/0000000000011099011
2015-08-25 15:07:19,725 DEBUG [RS_OPEN_REGION-ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:60020-2] zookeeper.ZKAssign: regionserver:60020-0x24f65d7e5df025c, quorum=ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX2.eu-west-1.compute.internal:2181,ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.internal:2181,ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX3.eu-west-1.compute.internal:2181, baseZNode=/hbase-unsecure Transitioned node 4945982779c1cba7b1726e77a45d405a from RS_ZK_REGION_OPENING to RS_ZK_REGION_OPENED
2015-08-25 15:07:19,725 DEBUG [RS_OPEN_REGION-ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:60020-2] handler.OpenRegionHandler: Transitioned 4945982779c1cba7b1726e77a45d405a to OPENED in zk on ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.internal,60020,1440528949321
2015-08-25 15:07:19,726 DEBUG [RS_OPEN_REGION-ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:60020-2] handler.OpenRegionHandler: Opened my-hbase-table,20150727.33,1438203991635.4945982779c1cba7b1726e77a45d405a. on ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.internal,60020,1440528949321
2015-08-25 15:07:19,733 DEBUG [RS_OPEN_REGION-ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:60020-1] zookeeper.ZKAssign: regionserver:60020-0x24f65d7e5df025c, quorum=ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX2.eu-west-1.compute.internal:2181,ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.internal:2181,ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX3.eu-west-1.compute.internal:2181, baseZNode=/hbase-unsecure Attempting to retransition opening state of node 3bc481ff534f0907e6b99d5eff1793f5
2015-08-25 15:07:19,734 DEBUG [RS_OPEN_REGION-ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:60020-1] regionserver.HRegion: Applied 0, skipped 1, firstSequenceidInLog=11099011, maxSequenceidInLog=11099011, path=hdfs://ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX2.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/apps/hbase/data/data/default/my-hbase-table/3bc481ff534f0907e6b99d5eff1793f5/recovered.edits/0000000000011099011
2015-08-25 15:07:19,734 DEBUG [RS_OPEN_REGION-ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:60020-1] regionserver.HRegion: Empty memstore size for the current region my-hbase-table,20150824.33,1440473855617.3bc481ff534f0907e6b99d5eff1793f5.
2015-08-25 15:07:19,737 DEBUG [RS_OPEN_REGION-ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:60020-1] regionserver.HRegion: Deleted recovered.edits file=hdfs://ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX2.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/apps/hbase/data/data/default/my-hbase-table/3bc481ff534f0907e6b99d5eff1793f5/recovered.edits/0000000000011099011
2015-08-25 15:07:19,759 DEBUG [RS_OPEN_REGION-ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:60020-1] wal.HLogUtil: Written region seqId to file:hdfs://ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX2.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/apps/hbase/data/data/default/my-hbase-table/3bc481ff534f0907e6b99d5eff1793f5/recovered.edits/11099013_seqid ,newSeqId=11099013 ,maxSeqId=11099010
2015-08-25 15:07:19,761 INFO  [RS_OPEN_REGION-ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:60020-1] regionserver.HRegion: Onlined 3bc481ff534f0907e6b99d5eff1793f5; next sequenceid=11099013
2015-08-25 15:07:19,764 DEBUG [RS_OPEN_REGION-ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:60020-1] zookeeper.ZKAssign: regionserver:60020-0x24f65d7e5df025c, quorum=ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX2.eu-west-1.compute.internal:2181,ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.internal:2181,ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX3.eu-west-1.compute.internal:2181, baseZNode=/hbase-unsecure Attempting to retransition opening state of node 3bc481ff534f0907e6b99d5eff1793f5
2015-08-25 15:07:19,773 INFO  [PostOpenDeployTasks:3bc481ff534f0907e6b99d5eff1793f5] regionserver.HRegionServer: Post open deploy tasks for region=my-hbase-table,20150824.33,1440473855617.3bc481ff534f0907e6b99d5eff1793f5.
2015-08-25 15:07:19,773 DEBUG [PostOpenDeployTasks:3bc481ff534f0907e6b99d5eff1793f5] regionserver.CompactSplitThread: Small Compaction requested: system; Because: Opening Region; compaction_queue=(0:1), split_queue=0, merge_queue=0
2015-08-25 15:07:19,774 DEBUG [regionserver60020-smallCompactions-1440529300855] compactions.RatioBasedCompactionPolicy: Selecting compaction from 4 store files, 0 compacting, 4 eligible, 10 blocking
2015-08-25 15:07:19,774 DEBUG [regionserver60020-smallCompactions-1440529300855] compactions.ExploringCompactionPolicy: Exploring compaction algorithm has selected 0 files of size 0 starting at candidate #-1 after considering 3 permutations with 0 in ratio
2015-08-25 15:07:19,774 DEBUG [regionserver60020-smallCompactions-1440529300855] compactions.RatioBasedCompactionPolicy: Not compacting files because we only have 0 files ready for compaction. Need 3 to initiate.
2015-08-25 15:07:19,775 DEBUG [regionserver60020-smallCompactions-1440529300855] regionserver.CompactSplitThread: Not compacting my-hbase-table,20150824.33,1440473855617.3bc481ff534f0907e6b99d5eff1793f5. because compaction request was cancelled
2015-08-25 15:07:19,787 INFO  [PostOpenDeployTasks:3bc481ff534f0907e6b99d5eff1793f5] catalog.MetaEditor: Updated row my-hbase-table,20150824.33,1440473855617.3bc481ff534f0907e6b99d5eff1793f5. with server=ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.internal,60020,1440528949321
2015-08-25 15:07:19,787 INFO  [PostOpenDeployTasks:3bc481ff534f0907e6b99d5eff1793f5] regionserver.HRegionServer: Finished post open deploy task for my-hbase-table,20150824.33,1440473855617.3bc481ff534f0907e6b99d5eff1793f5.
2015-08-25 15:07:19,788 DEBUG [RS_OPEN_REGION-ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:60020-1] zookeeper.ZKAssign: regionserver:60020-0x24f65d7e5df025c, quorum=ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX2.eu-west-1.compute.internal:2181,ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.internal:2181,ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX3.eu-west-1.compute.internal:2181, baseZNode=/hbase-unsecure Transitioning 3bc481ff534f0907e6b99d5eff1793f5 from RS_ZK_REGION_OPENING to RS_ZK_REGION_OPENED
2015-08-25 15:07:19,791 DEBUG [RS_OPEN_REGION-ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:60020-1] zookeeper.ZKAssign: regionserver:60020-0x24f65d7e5df025c, quorum=ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX2.eu-west-1.compute.internal:2181,ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.internal:2181,ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX3.eu-west-1.compute.internal:2181, baseZNode=/hbase-unsecure Transitioned node 3bc481ff534f0907e6b99d5eff1793f5 from RS_ZK_REGION_OPENING to RS_ZK_REGION_OPENED
2015-08-25 15:07:19,791 DEBUG [RS_OPEN_REGION-ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:60020-1] handler.OpenRegionHandler: Transitioned 3bc481ff534f0907e6b99d5eff1793f5 to OPENED in zk on ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.internal,60020,1440528949321
2015-08-25 15:07:19,791 DEBUG [RS_OPEN_REGION-ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:60020-1] handler.OpenRegionHandler: Opened my-hbase-table,20150824.33,1440473855617.3bc481ff534f0907e6b99d5eff1793f5. on ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.internal,60020,1440528949321
2015-08-25 15:07:20,344 INFO  [B.DefaultRpcServer.handler=3,queue=3,port=60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: Client tried to access missing scanner 1
2015-08-25 15:07:20,346 DEBUG [B.DefaultRpcServer.handler=3,queue=3,port=60020] ipc.RpcServer: B.DefaultRpcServer.handler=3,queue=3,port=60020: callId: 36 service: ClientService methodName: Scan size: 25 connection: 172.31.40.100:42285
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.UnknownScannerException: Name: 1, already closed?
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.scan(HRegionServer.java:3150)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:29994)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2078)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:108)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:114)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:94)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**EDITED 3:**

I've tried to do range scans within a row with a ColumnRangeFilter and it is working without putting down any region servers:

```
scan 'my-table', {STARTROW=>'row-key',ENDROW=>'row-key', FILTER=> ColumnRangeFilter.new(Bytes.toBytes('first_possible_column_prefix'),true,Bytes.toBytes('another_possible_column_prefix’),false)}
```

This code in Spark though is putting the region servers down, same behavior as before:

```
val scanPoints = new Scan()
scanPoints.setStartRow((queryDate+"."+venueId).getBytes())
scanPoints.setStopRow((queryDate+"."+venueId+"1").getBytes())
scanPoints.setFilter(new ColumnRangeFilter(Bytes.toBytes("first_possible_column_prefix"),true,Bytes.toBytes("another_possible_column_prefix"),false))
...
val confPoints = HBaseConfiguration.create()
confPoints.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, Utils.settings.HBaseWifiVisitorsTableName)
confPoints.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", Utils.settings.zQuorum);
confPoints.setInt("zookeeper.session.timeout", 6000000)
confPoints.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", Utils.settings.zPort);
confPoints.set("zookeeper.znode.parent",Utils.settings.HBaseZNode)
confPoints.set("hbase.master", Utils.settings.HBaseMaster)
confPoints.set("hbase.mapreduce.scan.column.family","positions")
confPoints.setLong("hbase.client.scanner.max.result.size",2147483648L)
confPoints.setLong("hbase.server.scanner.max.result.size",2147483648L)
confPoints.setInt("hbase.rpc.timeout",6000000)
confPoints.setInt("hbase.client.operation.timeout",6000000)
confPoints.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN, convertScanToString(scanPoints))
...
val rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(confPoints, classOf[TableInputFormat], classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result]).cache()
```

If I would be able to make this Spark Job to work, I could iterate through the whole row scanning intervals to process it entirely.

Comment: " The problem is that each row (1 cf) are ending up having millions of records" - can you add more information regarding this point.

Comment: I updated the question about that issue @Ramzy. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I still did not understand what you mean by - each row is having millions of rows. Can you elaborate on that

Comment: Sorry about that @Ramzy! What I was meaning is that millions of records end up having the same row key. Is there a way to scan only part of a row?

Comment: So all those rows end up handled by one region server and it could not handle tht load. Is that your problem? Also, do you have any other column qualifier to filter it up, so that we can reduce the scan range. Even this, is trick, because the choice of filter decides scan renage

Comment: Yes, I think that's the problem. There are no more column qualifiers. But as I can perform that filtered scan with the shell (that is a client) I suppose I should be able to perform it as well from Spark.

Comment: why dont you use map reduce, and use the parallel design it provides, to disribute the work, and then proceed. Spark works similarly, but it fetches entire data into RDD. general view is, you can go to spark, when you have memory to handle entire data set.